# Unable to submit via application loader

Tags: iphone, ios, application-loader

I get the following errors when trying to submit my app through application loader:

1: Apple's web service operation was not successful

2: Unable to authenticate package: 724054635.itsmp

3: ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The file is not a valid application bundle." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset(MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I really doubt it has anything to do with my certificates or anything, since I've retried the process multiple times. Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you using the latest Xcode?

Comment: Yes, everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip your .ipa file and check that there is a single "Payload" directory at the top level, with all your application files under that.

This resolved the problem for me when using the latest version of Application Loader (2.9) which is included with XCode 5. I tried under the previous version of Application Loader, distributed with XCode 4, and it did not have this problem.

Comment: My ipa seems fine, and I've attempted uploading with an old version of application loader. It still fails, but gives a different error:

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements

Comment: It feels like ipa files are checked much more under the newer Application Loader; the problem I encountered was just one example of what it picks up - sounds like you have a different issue. Even if you solve this, I believe you will then encounter the problem you see with the older version of Application Loader.